# ASP.NET Core 8 TypedResults.File with ETag always returning result from browser disk cache

Tags: c#, .net, etag

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 8 endpoint that returns a `TypedResults.File` with an ETag. First time I hit the endpoint, the file is returned 100% OK.

Second (and subsequent) times I hit the endpoint *with the same instance of the browser* I get an HTTP 200 OK (from disk cache) - it never makes the actual request to my localhost server.

Here's the network traffic of the 2x requests:

Request 1:

[image]

Request 2 (which grabs it from the disk cache)

[image]

I *thought* that if the initial request returns an ETag then the browser is "smart enough" to do subsequent requests with the ETag + "If-None-Match" request header?

This is the code that generated the File

```
var etag = new EntityTagHeaderValue($"\"{invoicePdfVersion}-{lastModifiedOn.Ticks}\"");

return TypedResults.File(
    pdfData, // byte array of pdf data 
    "application/pdf", // content type
    "testing", // filename
    false, // enable range processing
    lastModifiedOn, // DateTime when the file was last updated/modified
    etag); // etag value
```

I understand that I could add this to the response:

```
context.Response.Headers.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

which I think does stop the disk cache occurring but I'm not sure if this is required? Shouldn't the MS-Code for ReturnTypes.File set all the headers up correctly so I don't need to do anything else?

I have some server side code which checks the ETag:

```
if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.IfNoneMatch, out var ifNoneMatch) &&
    ifNoneMatch == etag.ToString())
{
    return TypedResults.StatusCode(304); // HTTP NotModified.
}
```

but of course, this never gets hit.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on ETag to always check with the server requires that the response headers include the `Cache-Control` header with the value `no-cache`.

Quoting from MDN:

> The no-cache response directive indicates that the response can be stored in caches, but the response must be validated with the origin server **before each reuse**, even when the cache is disconnected from the origin server.

The boldface part justifies this answer.

Comment: thank you @joserairez for the answer! Can you source this answer? Or explain with a bit more detail _why_ this is the case? Without the `Cache-Control:no-control` .. why is the ETag not getting passed through?

Comment: You can see the documentation for this in the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).  I updated my answer to include a quote.